# Wordpress以外で自作CMSを作りたいと思っています

Tags: wordpress, cms

何よりも軽い速いサイトを作りたいです。
当然VPSは高価な物になると思います。
AWSかGoogleCloudComputeか迷っています。
NginxやWCCなどでキャッシュをどうこうするのはあまりにも面倒です。
ブログサービスもありますが、PCスマホ広告のないサイトを作りたいです。

構造がものすごくシンプルなCMSとなると、やはり自作しか無いでしょうか？
ちなみに作りたいのはすべての自動車を解析したブログです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VPSが高価というなら他のクラウドサービスも安くはありません。
軽くて早いサイトとなると静的HTMLを出力するMovable Typeのようなブログや、静的ページとしてエクスポートできるMODxなどを利用するのが良いと思います。
静的ページであればサーバー性能よりネットワークなどのインフラやサーバーのリージョンが重要になるので、東京にリージョンのあるAWSを選択するのはひとつの手です。
ただし、突発的にアクセスが急増する可能性があるなら Google Compute Engine の柔軟性も魅力です。

Comment: GCEにしたいとます。ありがとございました